# Declare a variable independent of specific generic type in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

I'm writing a web wrapper view controller which dynamically uses the most appropriate web view class depending on the version of iOS on which it is run:

```
protocol WebViewCommon: class {
    func loadURL(url: NSURL)
    func disableBouncing()
    func haveLoadedPage() -> Bool
}

class WebWrapperViewController<T where T: UIView, T: WebViewCommon>: UIViewController {

    var loginUrl: NSURL!
    var webView: T!

    // ...
}
```

I then need to instantiate the correct generic version as follows:

```
    var webWrapperVC: WebWrapperViewController // compiler error

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        webWrapperVC = WebWrapperViewController<WKWebView>()
    } else {
        webWrapperVC = WebWrapperViewController<UIWebView>()
    }

    webWrapperVC.loginUrl = targetURL // access WebWrapperViewController specific API
    self.window!.rootViewController = webWrapperVC
```

the `var` declaration does not compile, with the following error:

> Reference to generic type 'WebWrapperViewController' requires
>   arguments in <...>

So far I have tried:

```
    var webWrapperVC: WebWrapperViewController<UIView<WebViewCommon>>
```

(which results in: "Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'WebViewCommon'")

and

```
    var webWrapperVC: WebWrapperViewController<T where T: UIView, T: WebViewCommon>
```

(which results in: "Expected '>' to complete generic argument list")

**My question is therefore: What is the correct `var` declaration in this instance?** As I need to access API that is specific to `WebWrapperViewController`, the `var` declaration needs to include this type.

Comment: why not optional?
var webWrapperVC: WebWrapperViewController?

Comment: Because I'm using an `if-else` statement, the variable will definitely get initialised. In fact, it's even valid Swift to declare as a `let` here.

And declaring as optional does not make the compiler error go away.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you need to use generics in this case. You have a protocol to use instead. Define the view controller without generics and use the protocol as the type for the webView.

```
class WebWrapperViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginUrl: NSURL?
    var webView: WebViewCommon?

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Then I get this compiler error: 'WebWrapperViewController' requires that 'WebViewCommon' inherit from 'UIView', which is why I also tried `var webWrapperVC: WebWrapperViewController<UIView<WebViewCommon>>`

Comment: If this is in `WebWrapperViewController ` then:
`var webWrapperVC: WebWrapperViewController<T>`

Comment: Sorry - this is in the `UIApplicationDelegate` subclass. I tried moving the logic of which generic version to construct to a static factory methor in `WebWrapperViewController` but experienced exactly the same problem with the return type of that function and `WebWrapperViewController<T>` did not cover it.